# Why session.getSaveBatch() is undefined when child record was added - Ext 5.1.1

Tags: session, model, extjs5

Well the title says it all, details following.

I have two related models, User & Role.

User has roles defined as:

```
Ext.define('App.model.security.User', {
    extend: 'App.model.Base',

    entityName: 'User',

    fields: [
        { name: 'id' },
        { name: 'email'},
        { name: 'name'},
        { name: 'enabled', type: 'bool'}
    ],

    manyToMany: 'Role'
});
```

Then I have a grid of users and a form to edit user's data including his roles.

The thing is, when I try to add or delete a role from the user a later call to session.getSaveBatch() returns undefined and then I cannot start the batch to send the modifications to the server.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this was interesting, I've learned a lot about Ext by solving this simple problem.

The solution I came across is to override the BatchVisitor class to make use of an event handler for the event onCleanRecord raised from the private method visitData of the Session class.

So for each record I look for left side entities in the matrix and if there is a change then I call the handler for onDirtyRecord which is defined on the BatchVisitor original class.

The code:

```
Ext.define('Ext.overrides.data.session.BatchVisitor', {
    override: 'Ext.data.session.BatchVisitor',

    onCleanRecord: function (record) {
        var matrices = record.session.matrices
            bucket = null,
            ops = [],
            recordId = record.id,
            className = record.$className;

        // Before anything I check that the record does not exists in the bucket
        // If it exists then any change on matrices will be considered (so leave)
        try {
            bucket = this.map[record.$className];
            ops.concat(bucket.create || [], bucket.destroy || [], bucket.update || []);

            var found = ops.findIndex(function (element, index, array) {
                if (element.id === recordId) {
                    return true;
                }
            });

            if (found != -1) {
                return;
            }

        }
        catch (e) {
            // Do nothing
        }

        // Now I look for changes on matrices
        for (name in matrices) {
            matrix = matrices[name].left;

            if (className === matrix.role.cls.$className) {
                slices = matrix.slices;

                for (id in slices) {
                    slice = slices[id];
                    members = slice.members;

                    for (id2 in members) {
                        id1 = members[id2][0]; // This is left side id, right side is index 1
                        state = members[id2][2];

                        if (id1 !== recordId) { // Not left side => leave
                            break;
                        }

                        if (state) { // Association changed
                            this.onDirtyRecord(record);
                            // Same case as above now it exists in the bucket (so leave)
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

It works very well for my needs, probably it wont be the best solution for others but can be a starting point anyways.

Finally, if it's not clear yet, what this does is give the method getSaveBatch the ability to detect changes on relationships.

Answer (score 0):

Well after reading a lot I found that Ext won't save the changed relationships between two models at least on 5.1.1.
I've had to workaround this by placing an aditional field on the left model (I named it isDirty) with a default value of false and set it true to force the session to send the update to the server with getSaveBatch.

Later I'll dig into the code to write an override to BatchVisitor or a custom BatchVisitor class that allow to save just associations automatically.

Note that this only occurs when you want to save just the association between the two models and if you also modify one of the involved entities then the association will be sent on the save batch.